Display text file and video simultaneously on TFT Display via Raspberry Pi
I want to create a Raspberry PI system which will connect to a HDMI Monitor. The display will continuously loop a video on the screen in the right half of the display. And the left half will show a single page pdf file. This should start automatically once the system boots up.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
